# the_content() not displaying the full post

Tags: posts, filters, the-content

When I use the_content() in the template php file, it displays the_excerpt() instead of the full post content.

I tried removing all filters with

```
remove_all_filters('the_content');
```

But it still displays the excerpt.

I found the workaround for displaying the full post content by fetching it directly from the database.

```
$post_data = get_post(get_the_ID());
echo $post_data->post_content;
```

This does not seem right though. I want to know why the_content() is not working and how to fix it?

List of all the plugins:

```
All-in-One WP Migration Version 7.18
Autocomplete WooCommerce Orders Version 1.1.0
Classic Editor Version 1.5 
Cloudflare Version 3.4.1 
Co-Authors Plus Version 3.4.2
Favorites Version 2.3.1 
Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights Version 7.10.4 
Gravity Forms Version 2.4.17    
Gravity Forms MailChimp Add-On Version 4.6 
Locations plugin Version 1.0.0
Order / Coupon / Subscription Export Import Plugin for WooCommerce (BASIC) Version 1.6.0 
Razorpay for WooCommerce Version 2.4.0  
Razorpay Subscriptions for WooCommerce Version 2.1.0 
Regenerate Thumbnails Version 3.1.3     
Teams for WooCommerce Memberships Version 1.2.1
Two Factor Authentication Version 1.7.2 
WooCommerce Version 3.9.0   
WooCommerce Extended Coupon Features FREE Version 3.1.2
WooCommerce Memberships Version 1.14.0 
WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips Version 2.4.6
WooCommerce Price Based on Country (Basic) Version 1.8.22 
WooCommerce Price Based on Country Pro Add-on Version 2.8.6
WooCommerce Stripe Gateway Version 4.3.1
WooCommerce Subscriptions Version 2.5.7
WooCommerce Subscriptions Gifting Version 2.1.0
WP Pusher Version 3.0.2 
Yoast SEO Premium
```

Theme:  A custom WordPress theme by Ink My Web

> Edited: I am using it in the single article page template of the blog. It does not happen in other pages. I think what happens is the WC membership plugin cuts off the content as it should happen for the free user. But when displaying for paid user, I need to show the full content.

Comment: Can you please switch back to a default theme (like TwentyTwenty etc.)? If things work there, then IMHO, this could be a theme-specific question, and if so, this question would be out of scope of this site. You can consult the [FAQ] for clarification.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I can't switch the theme. Can you suggest some other way?

Comment: Don't worry. There's always a way. Please refer to the [Debug tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info).

Comment: Please enlist all active plugins and your current theme (Own theme, Wordpress twenty series, 3rd party)

Comment: @Pmpr I have enlisted the plugins and theme. Can you check?

Comment: in what template file are you using `the_content()`? is that happening in all the locations where `the_content()` is used, like index.php or archive.php? are you using the 'more tag' in your posts?

Comment: @Michael No. Its not happening in all files.

Comment: in what template file are you using the code? are you using the 'more tag' in the post(s)? or is it showing the automatic generated excerpt?

Comment: @Michael I am using it in the single article page template of the blog. I think what happens is the WC membership plugin cuts off the content as it should happen for the free user. But when displaying for paid user, I need to show the full content.

Comment: I’m trying to remember what the tag/filter was for WooCommerce Memberships but I’ve encountered this before and sadly no longer have access to the site.  You are on the right track though and my guess would be that it’s with the membership plugin, and there is a straightforward workaround, I’ll see if I can dig up any snippets I may have saved.

Comment: @Michael And also it's working on my local i.e I can see the full content, but not on staging

Comment: @TonyDjukic Yees please. Thank you so much

Comment: Saeesh Tendulkar, unfortunately I don't appear to have any of the segments/solutions saved and the site in questions is from almost 3 years ago so I don't remember exactly what the issue was.  Can you do a quick check though - select a post where you're having this issue, go to edit it and temporarily 'Disable Restrictions'.
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/woocommerce-memberships-make-post-public.png

Like in the picture there - then check and see if that fixes the issue, if it does, we're a bit closer to isolating the problem.

Comment: @TonyDjukic No. It did not solve the issue by disabling the restrictions on that post. Maybe It applies the restrictions on all posts bymistake.

Comment: @TonyDjukic The plugin applies restriction to all posts by default because it is made to hide the content if user is not a member. That restriction does not get removed by remove_all_filters() is the issue here.

Comment: Saeesh Tendulkar, is it working for you now?

Comment: This is likely due to the memberships plugin - as it intercepts the_content (if its restricted) and ads the excerpt. Can you advise if the particular bit of content has a restriction rule in place?

Answer (score -1):

## Step 1

Disable all plugins and try enabling plugins, one by one, while you refresh the problematic page after each plugin enabled, until you find the source of problem.
If no plugin was the cause, go to step 2.

## Step 2

Edit your current theme's functions.php file and comment all occurrences of

```
add_action();
add_filter();
```

function calls, like this:

```
# add_action();
# add_filter();
```

Then try to uncomment them one by one, while you refresh the problematic page after each line uncommented, until you find the source of problem.

Comment: It's a live site which cannot go down. So I can't do that. Is there some way to debug without compromising the site?

Comment: You need a local copy for development purposes. Do not touch the production at all. install a local copy and test the provided solution if you really want to solve it.

Comment: I have a local copy. But thing is it's working on my local i.e. I can see the full post with the_content(), but not on production server.

Comment: according to your comment on the question, a plugin is the cause. please accept my answer and ask another question, if you have problem with one of your plugins, as your current question got an answer now.

Comment: Sorry but your answer didn't help me at all. I still haven't figured out the fix, so if you can help with that I'll be more than willing to accept your answer

Comment: Did you find the source of problem, using my method or not?!